# github picks up entire commit history

Tags: git, github

I have somehow picked up the entire commit history of the main branch in my latest pull request. My PR contains the message:

`This pull request is big! We’re only showing the most recent 250 commits.`

I have a branch that has a LOT of features. This is a working branch used for testing. I have to break up that branch into individual pull requests with each PR as a separate feature so they can be reviewed. There is some crossover with different features so these separate branches aren't going to be functional.

I branch off of `master` and then do an uncommitted merge with my latest working branch. I pick out the files I want to merge related to that feature. These PRs don't build upon one another. Each will be up-to-date with `master` but not each other.

What seems to be happening is that the target branch is picking up the entire history of the working branch. How can I keep this from happening? Could a rebase fix this?

Comment: I can see it quite a lot merging development branch to master. What is the problem?

Comment: Please see the edit on OP.

Comment: How are you doing these PRs?  Is it one per branch (and the branch dies), or is it multiple per branch?

Comment: It's kind of backwards. I develop a bunch of features on a working branch. Then, I go back and branch off of `master` and do an uncommitted merge with the working branch using SourceTree. This enables me to control what files go into the merge. I create a separate branch for each feature. If I could cherry pick individual files instead of whole commits, I wouldn't have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

> It's kind of backwards. I develop a bunch of features on a working branch. Then, I go back and branch off of master and do an uncommitted merge with the working branch using SourceTree. This enables me to control what files go into the merge. I create a separate branch for each feature. If I could cherry pick individual files instead of whole commits, I wouldn't have to do it this way.

Even if you don't commit the merge commit, you still have your working branch's HEAD as one of your parents, thus bringing along its history.

I think you can do what you want with `git reset`, but a far easier option is to create another clone, check out the working branch there, and copy over all the files to your checkout that's on the branch off of master.  Then you can stage whichever changes you'd like and formulate them into proper commits.

This would be a lot easier if your commits were atomic, as then you could simply cherry-pick commits over, as you say.  Doing a bit of work upfront in organizing your commits saves a lot of time later in trying to tease them apart.

Comment: How do I do it with `git reset`? I'm not sure I understand your solution. So I clone `master`, then I checkout the working branch. Then I "copy over all the files to your checkout that's on the branch off of master". How do I copy between branches? I can copy the files to a temp directory, switch branches and copy them over, but that's not easy at all and prone to error.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting using a temporary directory, but a temporary directory that is another checkout of the repo.  This would look something like 1) `git clone <my-github-address> /tmp/working-copy`  2) `cd /tmp/working-copy && git checkout working-branch` 3) `rsync -a /tmp/working-copy ~/awesome-project`  4) `cd ~/awesome-project && git status` .  Git will tell you which files have changed, so you can selectively stage them with `git add` and decide which ones to commit.

Comment: This actually didn't work. It just added `/tmp/working-copy` to `~/awesome-project`.

Comment: Sorry, rsync is particular about trailing slashes.  I believe you want `rsync -a /tmp/working-copy/ ~/awesome-project` .